# How do I download and install Nuget packages with PackageManagement Module?

Tags: powershell, nuget, package-management, oneget

How do I download and install Nuget packages with PackageManagement Module? I can't seem to find any packages when I run find-package -Source nuget.org or try to run the install with a package I see on nuget.org. Is there some configuration I am missing?

Comment: Why are you using nuget.org instead of powershellgallery?

Comment: I am dabbling in C# for a specific purpose and wanted to learn the nooks and crannies of package management in pwsh

Comment: Use `-ProviderName NuGet -Source https://www.nuget.org/packages`